# My env variable works on localhost but is undefined when deployed on Netlify

Tags: javascript, axios, get, environment-variables, netlify

Having trouble getting an axios GET request to work on Netlify because the env variable that defines my api key comes up as undefined on Netlify. I have already set the env variable with 'Site settings > Build & deploy > Environment > Environment variables'. But when I try it on Netlify I get:

```
GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&appid=undefined&units=imperial
error forecast: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401
```

Here is my code that makes the GET request:

```
import { Forecast } from './forecast';
import axios from 'axios';

export class DOM {
    static displayFiveDayForecast = (city) => {
        const BASE_URL_FIVE_DAY_FORECAST = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast';

        axios.get(`${BASE_URL_FIVE_DAY_FORECAST}?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}&units=imperial`)
        .then(res => {
            const weatherObj = Forecast.createForecasts(res.data);
            const content = document.getElementById('content');

            const forecastDiv = document.createElement('div');
            forecastDiv.id = 'forecast';
            content.appendChild(forecastDiv);

            for(let value in weatherObj.forecasts) {
                const forecastBox = document.createElement('div');
                forecastBox.className = 'forecast-item';
                forecastDiv.appendChild(forecastBox);

                const date = document.createElement('div');
                date.textContent = weatherObj.forecasts[value][0];
                forecastBox.appendChild(date);

                const icon = document.createElement('img');
                icon.src = weatherObj.forecasts[value][3];
                icon.alt = 'forecast icon';
                forecastBox.appendChild(icon);

                const main = document.createElement('div');
                main.textContent = `${weatherObj.forecasts[value][1]} F\u00B0`;
                forecastBox.appendChild(main);

                const feelsLike = document.createElement('div');
                feelsLike.textContent = `Feels like ${weatherObj.forecasts[value][2]} F\u00B0`;
                forecastBox.appendChild(feelsLike);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {console.log(`error forecast: ${err}`)})
    }
}
```

This GET request works fine on localhost and the api key is defined there. I'm using webpack if that information helps.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "javascript-weather-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A weather application using the openweather api",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "author": "tgoandrex",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    plugins : [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/template.html'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env)
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out all I had to do was define a variable in my function and set it as the environment variable. I still don't understand why this works and just taking `process.env.API_KEY` directly doesn't.

```
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
axios.get(`${BASE_URL_FIVE_DAY_FORECAST}?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=imperial`)
```